# WMI Activity consuming High CPU and Memory

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, wmi, windows-server-2019

I have a multiple production server with EC2 Windows 2019 based instances in Amazon Cloud. I'm facing issue that WMI Process make High CPU and High Memory. I have installed some third party agents such monitoring too agent and Anti-virus agent on all windows 2019 machines. If I stop the WMI Process in Task manager. Then some of agents too stopped.
I have checked the Process Id with event logs and searching the process id in Task manager. I can see some process with same ID.

[image: WMI Error]

I can see multiple error with same Event ID.

[image: WMI-Errors with 5858 Id]

Finally I update the patch using Amazon System Manager Server Patching. After completed the patching, Still I could see this errors and WMI Process. Is it legitimate process then why its consuming more CPU and Memory? How can I resolve this issues? Can any please help me out from this hell?

Comment: I can see the answer in stackoverflow when question is about Linux related. But when question post with windows mean there is no reply. Seems everyone using Linux based servers. Am I right?